# Get all taxonomy term and their acf image field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I am very new to wordpress theme development and I have created a custom post and custom taxonomy . I have created a image acf on taxonomy now I want to show all the taxonomy term and their acf fields on **front-page** . I can get all term by using **get_terms()** function but I don't know how to get acf field of that taxonomy.

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
"taxonomy" => "categories",
"hide_empty" => false ));
foreach($terms as $term): 
echo $term->name;
endforeach;
```

I want term name and image acf field of that term on front-page.php . Any advice will be helpful and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
<?php

$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), "categories");

if (!empty($terms)): ?>
    <ul>    
        <?php foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_field("image_field_name", $term); ?>" />
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul> 
<?php endif;
?>
```

For more details you can check this [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get taxonomies and acf fields related to them. Should work on Custom taxonomies too.

```
<?php

$categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'categories',// any term
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

if ($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $term_fields = get_fields('term_'.$cat->term_id);
        if ($term_fields) {
            $image = $term_fields['image'];
            //you have access to all image sizes
    ?>
    <img src="<?=$image['sizes']['large'];?>" alt="" />
  <?php
           
        }
    }
?>
```

Above code will work on wordpress > 5.5.0

To get term fields in different way you can follow [acf doc](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)